# Parameters to SqlCommand and SqlDataAtapter

Tags: sql, vb.net, sqlcommand, sqldataadapter

Have been working always with SQLDataAdapter and Fill command for data fetching querys   and with executenonquery for insert, update, delete ones.

I'm having a problem and can{t figure out what am I doing wrong.
I have a DataTable bind to a RadGrid. The DataTable gets the data for one particular month of a companys receipts and generates an extra column with info we need.

I get a selected month fron a RadControl and send the data after pressing a button:

```
    Protected Sub RadButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadButton1.Click
    Dim fecha As Date
    fecha = RadMonthYearPicker1.DbSelectedDate
    miDataTable = objOPRecibo.FacturasEspeciales(fecha.Month, fecha.Year)
    RadGrid1.Rebind()
End Sub
```

This is the function in the called object:

```
    Public Function FacturasEspeciales(Mes As Integer, Anio As Integer) As DataTable
    Dim FEDataTable As New DataTable
    Using conection As New SqlConnection(constr)
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand(@"SELECT 
              SUM(Det_Recibo.dCantidad) Cantidad, 
              Producto.Nombre, 
              SUM(Det_Recibo.mTotal) Valor, 
              SUM((((Det_Recibo.mTotal*100)/95)*1.12)) ESPE 
              FROM Det_Recibo 
                   INNER JOIN Enc_Recibo 
                   ON Det_Recibo.idRecibo = Enc_Recibo.idRecibo 
                   INNER JOIN Producto 
                   ON Det_Recibo.idProducto = Producto.IdProducto 
              WHERE MONTH(Enc_Recibo.dFechaFact)=@Mes AND 
                    YEAR(Enc_Recibo.dFechaFact)=@Anio 
                    Producto.idGasto = 1 OR Producto.idGasto = 2 
                    GROUP BY Producto.Nombre")
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mes", Mes)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Anio", Anio)

            Dim sda As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd.CommandText, conection)
            sda.Fill(FEDataTable)

        End Using
    End Using
    'Return DataTable
    Return FEDataTable
End Function
```

I{m getting either a not defined scalar error for @Mes or a second error not specific about the sda.Fill line.

I´m sort of a newbie and after hours of research I just can´t figure out what am I doing wrong.

Any help would be apreciated

Comment: Try `Dim sda As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)`

Comment: You are missing the AND/OR operator after the YEAR condition and before the Producto condition. Using the verbatim @ string makes the problem clear.

Comment: Thanks Steve will check that out when back at my desktop

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because of the missing  connection.Open()

```
Using conection As New SqlConnection(constr)
conection.open()
<REST OF YOUR CODE>
```

Comment: SqlDataAdapter opens the connection if it is closed.

Comment: Steve thanks ... good to know. @LarsTech has a better answer.